# overloading a class method to be able to index python objects in a list based on their attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Imagine that I have a class called `foo` and its definition is following

```
class foo:
     def __init__(self, id):
         self.id = id
```

and I want this to happen

```
dummylist = [foo(3), foo(4), foo(10)]

# I want to do that if possible

print(dummylist[10]) # and get the last object in the list
```

What I want is that I have a class with a lot of attributes and I want to have a list of objects of that class and would be able to retrieve a specific object with a value of its attribute.

I know that I can do that with `next` or list comprehension but I want to do so by indexing the list of object with `[]`

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you want to achieve !

Comment: Then you should create a dict with the id as key, rather than a list,

Comment: @mooga I edited the question

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Okay I know that by I want to do it with lists

Comment: `foo` has nothing to do with indexing; that's entirely determined by `list` (`dummylist.__getitem__(10)`), so you would need to define your own container for `foo` objects.

Comment: What you want is impossible. The elements of a list have no effect at all on indexing the list.

Comment: @chepner okay you are right

Comment: Are you looking for a dictionary perhaps, e.g. ``{3: foo(3), 10: foo(10)}``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know that it is impossible, but I thought maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no no I should define my own container as chepner said

Comment: I would recommend *not* doing anything like this, though. Indexing and value lookup are two different things. For instance, a lookup based on values (because they do not need to be unique) could return multiple results, while an indexing operation really should only return a single value corresponding to a unique key. Don't simply overload the `[]` operator to do something else.

Comment: @chepner you are 100% right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own list using [collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects):

```
from collections import UserList 


class myList(UserList):
    def _lookup(self, name):
        for item in self.data:
            if item.id == name:
                return item

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._lookup(name)

    def __call__(self, name):
        return self._lookup(name)


class foo:
     def __init__(self, id):
         self.id = id


dummylist = myList([foo(3), foo(4)])
dummylist.append(foo(10))
print(dummylist(10), dummylist(10).id)
print(dummylist[3], dummylist[3].id)
```

Out:

```
<__main__.foo object at 0x104a52460> 10
<__main__.foo object at 0x1049cfa00> 3
```

Comment: You can also subclass `list` directly (`UserList` predates the ability to do so).

Comment: This use-case seems a lot more suitable to base it on a ``dict``, not a ``list``.